# Storing multiple GeoTiffs in HDF5 file in Python

Tags: python, hdf5, geotiff

I want to store multiple GeoTiff files in one HDF5 file to use it for further analysis since the function I am supposed to use can just deal with HDF5 (so basically like a raster stack in R but stored in a HDF5). I have to use Python. I am relatively new to HDF5 format (and geoanalysis in Python generally) and don't really know how to approach this issue. Especially keeping the geolocation/projection inforation seems tricky to me. So far I tried:

```
import h5py
import rasterio

r1 = rasterio.open("filename.tif")
r2 = rasterio.open("filename2.tif")

with h5py.File('path/test.h5', 'w') as hdf:
    hdf.create_dataset('GeoTiff1', data=r1)
    hdf.create_dataset('GeoTiff2', data=r2)
```

Yielding the following errror:

```
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

I am pretty sure this not at all the correct approach and I'm happy about any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to do this:

```
import numpy as np
spec_dtype = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.dtype('float64'))
```

Just make a spec_dtype variable with float64 type then apply this to create_dataset:

```
with h5py.File('path/test.h5', 'w') as hdf:
    hdf.create_dataset('GeoTiff1', data=r1,, dtype=spec_dtype)
    hdf.create_dataset('GeoTiff2', data=r2,, dtype=spec_dtype)
```

Apply these and hopefully it will work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. When I implement that I get the follow error:
AttributeError: 'DatasetReader' object has no attribute 'dtype'
Which I think has something to do with the rasterio.open(). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) in Python, your use-case could be solved as follows:

```
import HDFql

HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET path/test.h5 GeoTiff1 VALUES FROM BINARY FILE filename.tif")

HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET path/test.h5 GeoTiff2 VALUES FROM BINARY FILE filename2.tif")
```